# When will Apple delete Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

My Apple ID has been locked because of security problems. Now I can't access or recover it. When will Apple delete this account? I want to re-create it after it is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

They may delete it someday, but they will never deactivate it — meaning, nobody will ever be able to use that Apple ID again. Use the "Contact us for help" link at https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204106 to get help re-claiming it.